# Translating Wordpress based on user language cookie

Tags: wordpress, localization, internationalization

Currently have a wordpress installation. I've created .mo files with translations but dont want to use wp-config.php to change the language. I want the language to change for the front end (for things such as "posted by:" etc) based on cookie we are creating when the user switches their language. I can't seem to find any way to do this. Is there a hook somewhere in wordpress where we can show the translations based on user cookie?

Comment: Taking a total guess, I would say no there isn't another hook because the other is a better practice. Why wouldn't you use the built in way?

Comment: So you want something like [WPML](http://wpml.org/)?

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress has already this functionality built in using the `gettext` utility., with a lot of plugins to facilitate the process for you .

One of the best is with no doubt the [qTranslate](http://wordpress.org/plugins/qtranslate/) plugin, which offers a lot of hooks and custom functions and operates in much the same way like you described. And it is free.